# Option value tree not reseting on first select

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a script with multiple select options, when you select an option new options will be visible. see fiddle!!

EX: if i select "Canapele" and then i select "Canapea Dana" other options will appear.
but if i select from first row (where i selected "Canapele") "Mobila" the options from "Canapea Dana" should be hidden.

i insert a button with "Reset" function but the other options still visible.

Any ideea how can i fix it?

See fiddle here  =>

https://jsfiddle.net/9d8qja4w/4/

***HTML***

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row-fluid">         <table>
<tbody>
<tr>


<td>
      <select id="Volum">
<option value="1x ">1x </option>
<option value="2x ">2x </option>
<option value="3x ">3x </option>
<option value="4x ">4x </option> 
<option value="5x ">5x </option> 
<option value="6x ">6x</option> 
</select></td>
 <td>     
<select id="produse">
<option value="reset">Selecteaza Produs</option>
<option value="Canapele">Canapele</option>
<option value="Mobila">Mobila</option>
<option value="Fotolii">Fotolii</option> 
<option value="Coltare">Coltare</option> 
<option value="Seturi">Seturi</option> 
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="ModeleColtare">
<option value="Coltar Vera">Coltar Vera</option>
<option value="Coltar Onix">Coltar Onix</option>
<option value="Coltar Olyve">Coltar Olyve</option>
<option value="Coltar Adrian">Coltar Adrian</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="ModeleSeturi">
<option value="Set Dana">Set Dana</option>
<option value="Set Ramona">Set Ramona</option>
<option value="Set Gina">Set Gina</option>
<option value="Set Olyve">Set Olyve</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="ModeleFotolii">
<option value="Fotoliu Gina">Fotoliu Gina</option>
<option value="Fotoliu Dana">Fotoliu Dana</option>
<option value="Fotoliu Ramona">Fotoliu Ramona</option>
<option value="Fotoliu Florin">Fotoliu Florin</option>
<option value="Fotoliu Olyve">Fotoliu Olyve</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="ModeleMobila">
<option value="Selecteaza Mobilierul">Selecteaza Mobilierul</option>
<option value="Birou Mic">  Birou Mic</option>
<option value="Birou Mare">    Birou Mare</option>
<option value="Comoda 3 Sertare">   Comoda 3 Sertare</option>
<option value="Comoda 4 Sertare">   Comoda 4 Sertare</option>
<option value="Comoda Katy">    Comoda Katy</option>
<option value="Comoda Alin">    Comoda Alin</option>
<option value="Cuier Sorin">    Cuier Sorin</option>
<option value="Cuier Mic">  Cuier Mic</option>
<option value="Cuier Perete">   Cuier Perete</option>
<option value="Cuier Mare"> Cuier Mare</option>
<option value="Dormitor Spot">  Dormitor Spot</option>
<option value="Dormitor Alin">  Dormitor Alin</option>
<option value="Dormitor Katy">  Dormitor Katy</option>
<option value="Living Modena">  Living Modena</option>
<option value="Masa Geo">   Masa Geo</option>
<option value="Masa Fantezie">  Masa Fantezie</option>
<option value="Masa Lorena Role">   Masa Lorena Role</option>
<option value="Masa TV Colt">   Masa TV Colt</option>
<option value="Masa Plianta">   Masa Plianta</option>
<option value="Masa TV Teava">  Masa TV Teava</option>
<option value="Masa TV Aripi">  Masa TV Aripi</option>
<option value="Masa Fantezie">  Masa Fantezie</option>
<option value="Masa Rotunda Pal">   Masa Rotunda Pal</option>
<option value="Noptiera Alin">  Noptiera Alin</option>
<option value="Noptiera Katy">  Noptiera Katy</option>
<option value="Pantofar 3 Sertare"> Pantofar 3 Sertare</option>
<option value="Pantofar 4 Sertare"> Pantofar 4 Sertare</option>
<option value="Pantofar California">    Pantofar California</option>
<option value="Pat Katy">   Pat Katy</option>
<option value="Pat Alin">   Pat Alin</option>
<option value="Scaun Spatar Fag">   Scaun Spatar Fag</option>
<option value="Taburet">    Taburet</option>
<option value="Sifonier 3 Usi S">   Sifonier 3 Usi S</option>
<option value="Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda">  Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda</option>
<option value="Sifonier Alin">  Sifonier Alin</option>
<option value="Sifonier Ana Cu Sticla"> Sifonier Ana Cu Sticla</option>
<option value="Sifonier Ana">   Sifonier Ana</option>
<option value="Sifonier Vally"> Sifonier Vally</option>
<option value="Soldat Dan"> Soldat Dan</option>
<option value="Sifonier Dan">   Sifonier Dan</option>
<option value="Sifonier Katy">  Sifonier Katy</option>
<option value="Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin"> Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin</option>
<option value="Sifonier 2 Usi"> Sifonier 2 Usi</option>
<option value="Sufragerie Vally">   Sufragerie Vally</option>
<option value="Sufragerie Dan"> Sufragerie Dan</option>
<option value="Sufragerie Ana"> Sufragerie Ana</option>
<option value="Sufragerie Tico">    Sufragerie Tico</option>
</select></td>


<td>
<select id="ModeleCanapele">
<option value="Canapea Dana">Canapea Dana</option>
<option value="Canapea Ramona">Canapea Ramona</option>
<option value="Canapea Tynca">Canapea Tynca</option> 
<option value="Canapea Gina">Canapea Gina</option>
<option value="Canapea Lyon">Canapea Lyon</option> 
<option value="Canapea Florin">Canapea Florin</option> 
<option value="Canapea Olyve">Canapea Olyve</option> 
<option value="Canapea Marina">Canapea Marina</option> 
<option value="Canapea Bya">Canapea Bya</option> 
</select></td>


<td>
<select id="Manere">
<option value="Selecteaza Brate">Selecteaza Dimensiunea Bratelor</option>
<option value="Brate 15 cm">Brate 15 cm</option>
<option value="Brate 10 cm">Brate 10 cm</option>
<option value="Brate 5 cm">Brate 5 cm</option> 
</select></td>

<td>
<select id="Perne">
<option value="Selecteaza Stofa Perne 1">Selecteaza Stofa Perne 1</option>
<option value="Stofa 1">Stofa 1</option>
<option value="Stofa 2">Stofa 2</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="Perne2">
<option value="Selecteaza Stofa Perne 2">Selecteaza Stofa Perne 2</option>
<option value="Fata Verso">Fata Verso</option>
<option value="Stofa 2">Stofa 2</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="Ornamente">
<option value="Selecteaza Ornamente Manere">Selecteaza Ornamente Manere</option>
<option value="Ornament Lyon">Ornament Lyon</option>
<option value="Ornamente Gina">Ornamente Gina</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="StofaPrincipala">
<option value="Selecteaza Stofa Principala">Selecteaza Stofa Principala</option>
<option value="Pireus 2">Pireus 2</option>
<option value="Muna 3">Muna 3</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="Piele">
<option value="Selecteaza Piele / Stofa">Selecteaza Piele / Stofa 2</option>
<option value="Piele 1">Piele 1</option>
<option value="Piele 3">Piele 3</option>
</select></td>



<td>
<select id="Pal1">
<option value="Selecteaza Pal 1">Selecteaza Pal 1</option>
<option value="Alb">Alb</option>
<option value="Nuc">Nuc</option>
</select></td>

<td>
<select id="Pal2">
<option value="Selecteaza Culoare Pal 2">Selecteaza Culoare Pal 2</option>
<option value="Alb2">Alb2</option>
<option value="Nuc2">Nuc2</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="Cheder">
<option value="Selecteaza Cheder">Selecteaza Culoare Cheder</option>
<option value="Cheder Alb">Cheder Alb</option>
<option value="Cheder Nuc">Cheder Nuc</option>
</select></td>

<td>
<select id="ManereMobila">
<option value="Selecteaza Tip Manere">Selecteaza Tip Manere</option>
<option value="Maner Rotund Inox">Maner Rotund Inox</option>
<option value="Maner Crom">Maner Crom</option>
<option value="Fara Maner">Fara Manere</option>
</select></td>

<td>
<select id="ParteSoldatCuiere">
<option value="Selecteaza Partea Soldat">Selecteaza Partea Soldat</option>
<option value="Soldat Stanga">Soldat Stanga</option>
<option value="Soldat Dreapta">Soldat Dreapta</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="ParteInsulaColtare">
<option value="Selecteaza Partea Insula">Selecteaza Partea Insula</option>
<option value="Insula Stanga">Insula Stanga</option>
<option value="Insula Dreapta">Insula Dreapta</option>
</select>
<td>
<select id="ParteMonitorBirouri">
<option value="Selecteaza Partea Monitor">Selecteaza Partea Monitor</option>
<option value="Monitor Stanga">Monitor Stanga</option>
<option value="Monitor Dreapta">Monitor Dreapta</option>
</select></td>
<td>
Alte Detalii: <textarea rows="1" style="width:120px;"></textarea> Pret: <input type="text" size="3" /> </td>
<td>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $("#filter").click(function(){
        //alert('clicked!');
        $('#produse').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#ModeleColtare').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#submitBtn').click();
    });
});

</script>

    <button id="filter" name="filter" onclick="resetFunction()">Reset</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

<div>
 <button id="addMore" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add Row</button>
 </div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
$("#addMore").click(function(){   
    $(".row-fluid:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");  
});

$("#produse").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Canapele'){
      $("#ModeleCanapele").show();
    }else{
      $("#ModeleCanapele").hide();
      $("#ModeleMobila").hide();
    }
});



   $("#produse").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Coltare'){
      $("#ModeleColtare").show();
    }else{
      $("#ModeleColtare").hide();
    }
    });
    // PARTE SOLDAT CUIERE
    $("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Cuier Mare' ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Sorin"){
      $("#ParteSoldatCuiere").show();
    }else{
      $("#ParteSoldatCuiere").hide();
      $("#ModeleColtare").hide();
    }
    });

        // PARTE INSULA COLTARE
    $("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Coltar Onix'){
      $("#ParteInsulaColtare").show();
    }else{
      $("#ParteInsulaColtare").hide();
    }
    });

    // PARTE MONITOR BIROURI
    $("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Birou Mare' ||
    $(this).val() == "Birou Mic"){
      $("#ParteMonitorBirouri").show();
    }else{
      $("#ParteMonitorBirouri").hide();
    }
    });



      $("#produse").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Seturi'){
      $("#ModeleSeturi").show();
    }else{
      $("#ModeleSeturi").hide();
    }
    });

     $("#produse").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Fotolii'){
      $("#ModeleFotolii").show();
    }else{
      $("#ModeleFotolii").hide();
    }
    });

// BRATE CANAPELE
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Florin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Dana")
    {
      $("#Manere").show();
     }else{
      $("#Manere").hide();
    }
});

// BRATE SETUURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Dana")
    {
      $("#Manere").show();
     }else{
      $("#Manere").hide();
    }
});

// BRATE FOTOLII
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Florin")
    {
      $("#Manere").show();
     }else{
      $("#Manere").hide();
    }
});
// Brate COLTARE
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian")
    {
      $("#Manere").show();
     }else{
      $("#Manere").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE CANAPELE
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Tynca" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Bya" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon")
    {
      $("#Perne").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE SETURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Gina")
    {
      $("#Perne").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne").hide();
    }
});


// PERNE Fotolii
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina")
    {
      $("#Perne").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE COLTARE
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Onix")
    {
      $("#Perne").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE2 canapele
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Tynca" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Bya" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon")
    {
      $("#Perne2").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne2").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE2 SETURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Gina")
    {
      $("#Perne2").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne2").hide();
    }
});

// PERNE2 COLTARE
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Onix")
    {
      $("#Perne2").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne2").hide();
    }
});


// PERNE2 Fotolii
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina")
    {
      $("#Perne2").show();
     }else{
      $("#Perne2").hide();
    }
});
// ORNAMENTE CANAPELE
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Florin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon")
    {
      $("#Ornamente").show();
     }else{
      $("#Ornamente").hide();
    }
});


// ORNAMENTE SETURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Dana")
    {
      $("#Ornamente").show();
     }else{
      $("#Ornamente").hide();
    }
});

// ORNAMENTE Fotolii
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Florin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Dana")
    {
      $("#Ornamente").show();
     }else{
      $("#Ornamente").hide();
    }
});

// ORNAMENTE COLTARE
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian")
    {
      $("#Ornamente").show();
     }else{
      $("#Ornamente").hide();
    }
});


// STOFA Principala CANAPELE
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Tynca" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Bya" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Florin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Marina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Olyve")
    {
      $("#StofaPrincipala").show();
     }else{
      $("#StofaPrincipala").hide();
    }
});


// STOFA Principala SETURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Olyve")
    {
      $("#StofaPrincipala").show();
     }else{
      $("#StofaPrincipala").hide();
    }
});


// STOFA Principala Fotolii
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Olyve" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Florin")
    {
      $("#StofaPrincipala").show();
     }else{
      $("#StofaPrincipala").hide();
    }
});

// STOFA Principala Coltare
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Onix" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Olyve")
    {
      $("#StofaPrincipala").show();
     }else{
      $("#StofaPrincipala").hide();
    }
});

// Piele/ STOFA Secundara SETURI
$("#ModeleSeturi").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Set Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Set Olyve")
    {
      $("#Piele").show();
     }else{
      $("#Piele").hide();
    }
});

// PIELE / STOFA SECUNDARA CANAPELE
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Tynca" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Lyon" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Bya" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Florin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Marina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Canapea Olyve")
    {
      $("#Piele").show();
     }else{
      $("#Piele").hide();
    }
});


// PIELE /STOFA Secundara Fotolii
$("#ModeleFotolii").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Fotoliu Dana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Ramona" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Gina" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Olyve" ||
    $(this).val() == "Fotoliu Florin")
    {
      $("#Piele").show();
     }else{
      $("#Piele").hide();
    }
});

// PIELE / STOFA SECUNDARA COLTARE
$("#ModeleColtare").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Coltar Vera" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Onix" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Adrian" ||
    $(this).val() == "Coltar Olyve")
    {
      $("#Piele").show();
     }else{
      $("#Piele").hide();
    }
});


$("#produse").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Mobila'){
      $("#ModeleMobila").show();
    }else{
      $("#ModeleMobila").hide();

    }



});


// PAL 1 Canapele
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Marina")
    {
      $("#Pal1").show();
     }else{
      $("#Pal1").hide();
    }
});

// PAL 1 MOBILA
$("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Birou Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Birou Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Sorin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Perete" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Spot" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Living Modena" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Geo" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Lorena Role" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Colt" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Plianta" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Teava" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Aripi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Rotunda Pal" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar California" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Scaun Spatar Fag" ||
    $(this).val() == "Taburet" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi S" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda" 
    ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana Cu Sticla" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Soldat Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Tico")
    {
      $("#Pal1").show();
     }else{
      $("#Pal1").hide();
    }
});


// PAL 2
$("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Birou Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Birou Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Sorin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Perete" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Spot" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Living Modena" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Geo" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Lorena Role" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Colt" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Plianta" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Teava" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Aripi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Rotunda Pal" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar California" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Scaun Spatar Fag" ||
    $(this).val() == "Taburet" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi S" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda" 
    ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana Cu Sticla" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Soldat Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Tico")
    {
      $("#Pal2").show();
     }else{
      $("#Pal2").hide();
    }
});

// Cheder Canapele
$("#ModeleCanapele").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Canapea Marina")
    {
      $("#Cheder").show();
     }else{
      $("#Cheder").hide();
    }
});


// Cheder Mobila
$("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Birou Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Birou Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Sorin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Spot" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Living Modena" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Lorena Role" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Teava" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Aripi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Fantezie" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Rotunda Pal" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi S" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda" 
    ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Tico")
    {
      $("#Cheder").show();
     }else{
      $("#Cheder").hide();
    }
});



// PAL 2
$("#ModeleMobila").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Birou Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Birou Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Comoda Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Sorin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mic" ||
    $(this).val() == "Cuier Mare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Spot" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Dormitor Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Living Modena" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Colt" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa Plianta" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Teava" ||
    $(this).val() == "Masa TV Aripi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Noptiera Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 3 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar 4 Sertare" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pantofar California" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Pat Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Taburet" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi S" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi cu Oglinda" 
    ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Alin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana Cu Sticla" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Soldat Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier Katy" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 3 Usi Magazin" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sifonier 2 Usi" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Vally" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Dan" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Ana" ||
    $(this).val() == "Sufragerie Tico")
    {
      $("#ManereMobila").show();
     }else{
      $("#ManereMobila").hide();
    }
});
```

***CSS***

```
#ModeleCanapele, #Manere, #Perne, #ModeleMobila, #Perne2, #Ornamente, #StofaPrincipala, #Piele, #Pal1, #Cheder, #Pal2, #ManereMobila, #ModeleColtare, #ModeleFotolii, #ModeleSeturi, #ParteSoldatCuiere, #ParteInsulaColtare, #ParteMonitorBirouri{
    display: none;
}




.new-rect {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Add a class to all your sub-selects, so you can hide them all in one function

```
<select id="ModeleCanapele" class="sub_select_class">
```

2/ Put only one change listener for a given select and use a switch.

```
$("#produse").change(function(){
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(); // save value
    $('.sub_select_class').hide(); // we hide every second select
    switch(value) { // we show only what needs to be visible
       case 'Canapele':
         $("#ModeleCanapele").show();
         break;
       case 'Coltare':
         $("#ModeleColtare").show();
         break;
       // ...etc
    }
});
```

Comment: got it, i have updated the JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/9d8qja4w/5/ as you told me, the problem is that now the first category will be hidden so you cannot change it.

Comment: ohh it works, i have just removed the class="sub_select_class" from first option

Comment: could you please check my fiddle see why if i click Add Row , the added row isnt working? https://jsfiddle.net/9d8qja4w/6/

Comment: Because the jquery selector of the eventlistener is set at the page load. If you create another row, the new one is not taken into account.
To solve it, you have to write 
`$(document).on('change', '#produse', function(){});`
instead of 
`$("#produse").change(function(){});`

Comment: But you can't add new rows because you can't have two objects with the same id on your page. You have to use classes instead like  `.produse_class` for instance